# How to set minimum CPU frequency?

Tags: cpu, cpufreq, cpupower

I am trying to set the minimum frequency of my CPU in ubuntu. Basically, the minimum my CPU runs in Windows is 2%, and in ubuntu it is 19%. Is there some way to change it from 19% to 2%? I tried using `cpupower` and the "CPU power manager" app, but I cannot get it to go lower than 19%.

In my CPU, 19% = 0.8 GHz.

Comment: When you say "Windows is 2%", are you referring to your CPU usage or the percentage of maximum frequency? I find it highly unlikely that Windows is operating on just 80MHz unless you're using *Windows 3.1.1 for Workgroups* 

Comment: I am referring to windows CPU usage. I guess my question would be if it possible to bring the CPU lower than 800 MHz?

Comment: CPU usage and CPU operating frequencies are not always aligned 1:1 so, if the goal is to get CPU usage down as much as possible, then you'll need to decide what sort of background services you can do without or, if you're willing to experiment a bit, you could try Ubuntu MATE, Xubuntu, and Lubuntu to find which one consumes the least amount of resources for your hardware. CPU frequency scaling is generally best left to the OS 

Comment: Thanks! So there is no way to ser it to 5% usage without turning off some background services?

Comment: I am not 100% clear on what you are trying to do, to be honest. If you want to reduce CPU load, you need to tell the OS to not run as much software. If you want to reduce the CPU frequency, you need to understand the computer will require more time to complete the same workload. If you want to do both, maybe an OS with a GUI isn't what you're looking for ...